# Downgrading the Stripe Subscription results in user refund

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I looked around at other solutions but none of them seem to be use case for me. We're not using webhooks instead Cron jobs on the 1st of the month after payments are processed.

My service offers X hours per month.

When user subscriptions they get X hours.
When the user upgrades they immediately get X hours difference between the two, only on upgrade. This works great, the sum is correct.

My issue is that when the user downgrade stripe issues a refund on the next invoice, incorret.

Here is an example that is incorrect, apprentely the user has nothing to pay the next billing cycle which makes no sense; they should pay the downgraded cost.

[image]

The code looks like so:

If it's an upgrade:

```
subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.update(existingSub.id, {
    cancel_at_period_end: false,
    proration_behavior: "always_invoice",
    default_tax_rates: [taxRate.id],
    items: [
        {
            // We need to upgrade the existing item.
            id: existingSub.items.data[0].id,
            price: price.id,
            quantity: 1,
        },
    ],
});
```

If it's a new sub

```
await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: req.user.stripeCustomerId,
    items: [
        {
            price: price.id,
        },
    ],
    billing_cycle_anchor: endOfMonth.unix(),
    default_tax_rates: [taxRate.id],
    metadata: {
        productId,
        paymentMethodId,
        amount,
        userUid: req.user.uid,
    },
    default_payment_method: paymentMethodId,
});
```

I'm not sure how to downgrade.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario above, the user has already paid for the subscription upfront. When you downgraded the subscription, the difference between the subscriptions was pro-rated and credited to the Customer credit balance [0] and applied to the next invoice.

If you don’t want the difference to be prorated when downgrading (maybe your company has a no refund policy), then you would want to apply `proration_behavior='none'` [1] when downgrading

You can read more about upgrading/downgrading subscriptions here : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade

[0]https://stripe.com/docs/billing/customer/balance#examples
[1]https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-proration_behavior

Comment: Yes I understand but the problem with proration_behavior='none' is that there's no charge for the new subscription on upgrade. When upgrading also it uses credit which is annoying. It seems like it's not possible without cancelling the subscription.

Comment: If you want the customer to immediately pay the price difference when switching to a more expensive subscription on the same billing cycle, you can set `proration_behavior=always_invoice` [0], which will calculate the proration and then immediately generate an invoice after making the switch. You can combine this behavior with pending updates so that the subscription is only updated if payment succeeds on the new invoice.  
[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-proration_behavior

Comment: the complication here is that you would have to implement some logic to determine if it's an upgrade/downgrade. You would probably want to do this by [previewing the upcoming invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming) by updating the [subscription_items.price](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming#upcoming_invoice-subscription_items-price)

Comment: Is there a way to refund the user instead of crediting to Credit Balance?

Comment: no, it's not possible to automatically refund the credit after downgrading a subscription. Stripe doesn't provide this feature at this point of time. You'll have to implement your own logic to refund the customer.